# How to show JPanel over another JPanel and then hide it

Tags: java, swing, awt

So Id like to have 2 JPanels. Up JPanel (introPanel) and down JPanel (mainPanel). Id like to add keyListener to JFrame so when I press any key up panel hides so we can see down panel. How should the code look like to work?

```
class MainFrame extends JFrame {
    private MainPanel mainPanel = new MainPanel();
    private IntroPanel introPanel = new IntroPanel();

    MainFrame() {
        add(mainPanel);
        add(introPanel);
        setResizable(false);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ev) {
                introPanel.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

This code doesn't hide introPanel. What's wrong?

Comment: You probably have to force a redraw. Setting to visibile(false) doesn't make it disappear, it just tells it not to draw on next render.

Comment: You mean to call repaint()? I even called revalidate() and nothing happened

Comment: Is this the only thing in it that doesn't work? Are there other graphics that do work?

Comment: Try setting resizeable to true for a minute, then change the size with your mouse. Does the intro screen disappear?

Comment: OK, I solved it. On key press I add MainPanel and hide IntroPanel. It works as I wanted.

Comment: Put both panels in a parent panel and add it to a `JScrollPane`.

Answer (score 3):

You can only place one component in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position so the `introPanel` displaces `mainPanel` when it is added. You have to add the `mainPanel` if you wish that to appear:

```
add(mainPanel);
revalidate();
repaint();
```

Consider using a [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). It supports the notion of "stacking" components in this manner.

Also consider using [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for Swing based applications. Unlike `KeyListeners`, Key Bindings do not require focus to interact with `KeyEvents`.

Comment: But this key listener works. I added line: "System.out.println("a");" and it prints "a" every time I press key

Comment: @user2080377 it might work ow, but KeyListeners are famous for suddenly stop working when you make a small change. The component they are registered to must be focasable and have focus to work. Key Bindings is a much more flexible API and is the recommended method of attaching key events to components

Comment: +! Good answer.  I still think the OP should put both panels in one `JScrollPane` though.  It seems 'designed' for this use.